# Class heritage in Python with dynamically generated method

Tags: python, constructor, python-class

I've created a module that includes 3 main things:

1. A main class with a `__new__` method and child classes that inherit this one;
2. A `make_method` decorator that can associate a method to an existing class:

```py
def make_method(obj):
    '''Decorator to make the function a method of *obj*.
    In the current context::
      @make_method(Axes)
      def toto(ax, ...):
          ...
    makes *toto* a method of `Axes`, so that one can directly use:
      ax.toto()
    COPYRIGHT: from Yannick Copin
    '''
    def decorate(f):
        setattr(obj, f.__name__, f)
        return f
    return decorate
```

3. A `generic` class.

The main class has a `__new__` method that uses the `make_method` decorator to create a plotting function that will work for any child class. Here is the example:

```py
class MainClass():

    FREEPARAMETERS = ['mu_1', 'sigma_1']
    PLTALL = ["self.param['" + k + "']" for k in FREEPARAMETERS]

    def __new__(cls, *arg, **kwargs):
        '''Returns the class with dynamically generated methods'''
        obj = super(MainClass, cls).__new__(cls)

        exec("@make_method(MainClass)\n" +
             "def plot_a(self, x_lin):\n" +
             "    return self.likelihood_tot(x_lin, %s)"
             % (", ".join(MainClass.PLTALL)))

       return(obj)
```

Then, if I create a `ChildClass` that way:

```py
class ChildClass(MainClass):

    FREEPARAMETERS = ['mu_1', 'sigma_1', 'mu_2', 'sigma_2']
    PLTALL = ["self.param['" + k + "']" for k in FREEPARAMETERS]
```

it will have a `plot_a` method that will only require to have an `x_lin` without having to enter the parameters by hand (provided a `likelihood_tot` method that takes the correct parameters).

All of that works very well (it may be a bit of an overkill for what I actually need but it's sweet). Then comes the `generic` class:

```py
class generic():
    '''Usage:
       gen = MyModule.generic()
       gen.set_model('model')
       fitted_model_1 = gen.fit(dataset1)
       fitted_model_2 = gen.fit(dataset2)

       fitted_model_1.plot_a(x_lin)
       fitted_model_2.plot_a(x_lin)'''

    def set_model(self, classname):
        '''Associates an uninstantiated class to self.model from its string'''
        self.model = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], classname)

    def fit(self, dataset, **kwargs):
        '''Instantiates the class with the pandas,
        apply the `minimize` method,
        and gives that back as an output'''

        model = self.model(dataset)
        model.minimize(**kwargs)
        return(model)
```

As stated in its documentation, the idea is to be able to call for a generic model to which I can for example pass different datasets without having to manually instance the class every time. Works fine.

The issue arises when doing the following, where `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` have different `FREEPARAMETERS`:

```py
gen.set_model('ChildClass1')
fitted_childclass1 = gen.fit(dataset)

gen.set_model('ChildClass2')
fitted_childclass2 = gen.fit(dataset)

fitted_childclass2.plot_a(x_lin)
fitted_childclass1.plot_a(x_lin)
```

The first `plot_a(x_lin)`, associated with the last call of the `generic` class, works fine. The second, however, gives me a `KeyError: 'mu_2'` or a `TypeError: likelihood_tot() missing n required positional arguments` depending on the relative number of `FREEPARAMETERS` between the latest instanced class and the one before, which means that somehow, **the dynamically generated `plot_a` of `fitted_childclass1` now has the parameters of `fitted_childclass2`**.

Yet, when calling for `childclass1.PLTALL` or `childclass2.PLTALL`, I do get the expected result. It would seem that they are not interchanged after instantiation. All methods that are not dynamically generated are correct.

I can of course call the `plot_a` functions in between each, but that's obviously not the point. I would like both `childclass1` and `childclass2` to behave as if I instantiated them like:

```py
childclass1 = MyModule.ChildClass1(dataset)
childclass1.minimize()
childclass2 = MyModule.ChildClass2(dataset)
childclass2.minimize()
```

Comment: Your use of `make_method` is **altering** `MainClass` every time.  That’s surely not what you mean; why can’t you just use a `classmethod`?